Can a function be represented in an infinite sum other than the Taylor Series?
Like instead of an infinite polynomial, and infinite sum of exponentials? Or sine waves? The function in question is $z/(e^z-1)$ and I am trying to convert it to an infinite sum to make the fractional derivative easier to take, but when I tried a Taylor Series I found that when the k-value in $$\sum^\infty_{n=0}f^{(n)}(k)(x-k)^n/n!$$ was altered, the values on the fractional derivative would change drastically, with the exception of positive integer derivatives. Why is this? And are their other infinite series that could represent my function as a sum of simpler ones?

have you heard of Fourier Series? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series

There are other possibilities , for example Tchebycheff-series. Has some adavantages compared to Taylor.

The keyword is series expansion. Wikipedia lists a few other types of series expansions like "the" Fourier series. There are also other power series like the Laurent series and the Puiseux series.

How about $$\frac{z}{e^z-1}=z \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-n z}$$ for example?
